# Expo-react-native :Couldn't adb reverse: device 'adb' not found

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, expo, adb

I am using react-native-expo for mobile app development.
I use an android emulator for the app, vscode editor for development.
It started showing me this error from  few days.

```
› Opening on Android...
Couldn't adb reverse: device 'adb' not found
› Opening exp://10.0.46.81:19000 on Device adb
Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: device 'adb' not found
› Press ? │ show all commands
```

I tried wiping the emulator, tapping on the build number in the emulator, but nothing worked out.

I've deleted the virtual devices and created new one. It worked for one time and again this process isn't working.
there isn't much about this on the internet.
need help.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I created a new emulator from the AVD manager. however, I couldn't figure out the reason why it is happening but whenever I face this issue I create a new emulator which works for me. Cold boot is not working in my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fix for me was to install the SDK Platform for the android version used by the AVD.

*In my case, I installed android v9 (Pie) via the **AVD Manager** when setting up my AVD for the first time, and when I looked into this issue I noticed that the **SDK Platform** for v9 was not installed as part of that setup.*

The exact steps I took are as follows:

*Disclaimer: You might not need to follow these steps exactly to resolve the issue*

1. Close all CMD and IDE programs.
2. Open Android Studio and navigate to AVD Manager
3. Click the **down arrow** for the target AVD and click the **Edit** option
4. Set the device to **Cold boot** instead of **Quick boot**
5. Open SDK Manager, and download the SDK Platform for android version used by AVD
6. Go back to AVD Manager, click the **Cold boot now** option
7. Open a CMD terminal as administrator, CD to project repo, and run **expo start**
8. Launch expo in AVD

DONE

Answer (score 9):

Just try this. It is work for me.

1. make sure you already add android sdk path in setting > appearance & behavior > system settings > android SDK > android SDK location
   (Common path is C:\Users(name)\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
2. create new variable name and value in Environment Variables (User Variables)
   (ANDROID_HOME  C:\Users(name)\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
3. add new Path in Environment Variables (User Variables)
   (C:\Users(name)\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools)

It is work for me after I have solved it for 3 hours.
At first, I don't face the problem like this in flutter but in react-native.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Emulator started working after this:

1. Delete caches from Android Studio
2. Wipe data from your emulator
3. Cold boot to restart

When I was solving this problem I also ended up doing these:

1. Check Android studio updates
2. Reinstalled Android studio
3. Check SDK updates from SDK tools: SDK Manager -> Android SDK -> SDK tools. You can see if there is a new update available on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Virtual Device Manager -> Select your Device -> Actions -> Click "Drop down" button and select "Cold Boot Now".

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I went to the avd and simply clicked "wipe data", restarted both my avd and server and it worked

Answer (score 0):

By my side the problem was is In `Internet Connection`. I just changed the **WiFi** and everything working fine.